# Change the borderStyle of the TextBox

Tags: winforms, textbox, styles, border, custom-controls

Is there any way that I can custom the border style of a winform textbox control as the images shown below?

[image]

I did search the answer for my question on Internet but there are NOT the results related to hide the top, left, right borders and the bottom border is dotted style.

I am wondering that I can do it with winform control or not?

please advise!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do, is inheriting from the Panel class and encapsulating a TextBox in it. Then override the OnPaint-event of that Panel to draw the things you want.

```
public class CustomTextBox : Panel
{
    private Color _nBorderColor = Color.Gray;
    private Color _fBorderColor = Color.Black;

    public TextBox _textBox;

    public CustomTextBox()
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.Padding = new Padding(2);

        _textBox = new TextBox();
        _textBox.AutoSize = false;
        _textBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        _textBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        _textBox.Enter += new EventHandler(TextBox_Refresh);
        _textBox.Leave += new EventHandler(TextBox_Refresh);
        _textBox.Resize += new EventHandler(TextBox_Refresh);
        this.Controls.Add(_textBox);
    }

    private void TextBox_Refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(SystemColors.Window);
        using (Pen borderPen = new Pen(this._textBox.Focused ? _fBorderColor : _nBorderColor))
        {
            borderPen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot;
            borderPen.Width = 3;
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(borderPen, 0, this.ClientSize.Height - 1, this.ClientSize.Width - 1, this.ClientSize.Height - 1);
        }
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```